# Mysql DATE_ADD 1 hour and I want minutes be 15, or 30

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

What I want to do is Add 1 hour to current date + make the minutes be in 15 minutes or 30 minutes.
Example:

```
'2022-05-19 22:13:28'

I want it to be :

'2022-05-19 23:15:00'
```

Another example

```
'2022-05-19 22:24:00'

I want it to be:

'2022-05-19 23:30:00'
```

Comment: what about 2022-05-19 22:15:00?  does it become 23:15 or 23:30?  does 21:59:00 become 23:00? or 23:15?  does 21:44:00 become 22:45 or 23:15?

Comment: also, I'm assuming these are UTC times.  If they are some other timezone, please say which.

Comment: yeah 21:59:00 become 23:00:00

Comment: and 21:44:00 become 22:45:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(3600 + 900 * CEIL(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime_column) / 900))
FROM table
```

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP` converts datetime to the seconds amount.

`/ 900` calculates the amount of 15min. blocks in it.

`CEIL` convert incomplete last block to complete one.

`* 900` converts blocks amount back to seconds.

`+ 3600` adds an hour.

`FROM_UNIXTIME` converts seconds amount to datetime.

Comment: this will be incorrect sometimes if datetime_column is utc and the session timezone uses daylight saving

Answer (score 0):

Assuming if it already on an even 15 minutes it just gets an hour added, you have to do some math on the time, then re-add it to the date:

```
select date_add(date(d), interval ceil(time_to_sec(d)/900)*900+3600 second)
from (select '2022-05-19 22:13:28' d union all select '2022-05-19 22:24:00' union all select '2022-05-19 22:15:00' union all select '2022-05-19 21:59:00' union all select '2022-05-19 21:44:00') foo
```

Dividing by 900 seconds, ceil'ing, and multiplying by 900 rounds it up to the nearest even 15 minutes.